# scripty2 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, scripty2

I can't make scripty2 to work..

```
$('tst').morph('border:12px solid #abc', { duration: .7 });

alert($('tst'));
alert($('tst').morph);
```

the first alert returns the element and the second returns a function

Comment: What are you expecting the alerts to return instead?

Comment: Of course `$('tst').morph` returns a function. `$('tst').morph` *is* a function - otherwise you couldn't call it in your first line ;)

Comment: I was using the alerts to find an error.. but it looks ok

Comment: @clarkk what is the problem then? Does the morphing not work?

Comment: the morph doesn't do anything to the element

Comment: Strange, looks okay. Does it work with a property different from `border`, like `background-color` ?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @clarkk: *"I were using the alerts to find an error"* Don't take this the wrong way (it's not meant as a dig), but there is [no longer any excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) for `alert`-based debugging. Use a debugger. They're free, they're mostly built-in, and a *lot* more useful.

Comment: it works with the background property :)

Comment: the morph was copied from the scripty2 docs

Comment: @clarkk done - so they have broken examples on their docs? Argh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting the properties into `border-color`, `border-width` and `border-style` - maybe Scripty can't handle shorthand.